# Where is sum(vin) > sum(vout) check in Bitcoin Core?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-core-development, transaction-verification

I'm searching the function that validates a transaction according to [Protocol rules - "tx" messages](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_rules#.22tx.22_messages) especially step 14 `sum(vin) > sum(vout)`.

I found [this](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/f7a21dae5dbf71d5bc00485215e84e6f2b309d0a/src/main.cpp#L939) interesting function `CheckTransaction(const CTransaction& tx, CValidationState &state)` but it does not validate step 14, right?

Where is this check for step 14?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/search?q=bad-txns-in-belowout&unscoped_q=bad-txns-in-belowout

```
const CAmount value_out = tx.GetValueOut();
if (nValueIn < value_out) {
    return state.DoS(100, false, REJECT_INVALID, "bad-txns-in-belowout", false,
        strprintf("value in (%s) < value out (%s)", FormatMoney(nValueIn), FormatMoney(value_out)));
}
```